# Как загрузить несколько файлов и записать их имена в базу данных?

Tags: php, pdo

Есть многофайловая загрузка изображений, но в БД создается только одна строка!

А нужно, чтобы все пути загружаемых файлов записывались в БД!

Вот код загрузки изображений:

```html
function upload_image()
{
  if(isset($_FILES['user_image']))
  {
    // Count total files
    $countfiles = count($_FILES['user_image']['name']);

    for($i=0;$i<$countfiles;$i++){
      $extension = explode('.', $_FILES['user_image']['name'][$i]);
      $new_name = rand() . '.' . $extension[1];
      $destination = '../portfolio/upload/' . $new_name;
      $thumbDestination = '../portfolio/upload/thumb/' . $new_name;
      
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES['user_image']['tmp_name'][$i], $destination);
      
      resize($destination, $thumbDestination, 300);
    }
    return $new_name;
  }
}
```

Вот код записи в БД:

```html
if($_POST["operation"] == "Add")
  {
    $image = '';
    if($_FILES["user_image"]["name"] != '')
    {
      $image = upload_image();
    }
    $statement = $connection->prepare("
      INSERT INTO portfolio (image, image_mini) 
      VALUES (:image, :image_mini)
    ");
    $result = $statement->execute(
      array(
        ':image'  => $image,
        ':image_mini'  => $image
      )
    );
    if(!empty($result))
    {
      echo 'Фото Добавлено';
    }
  }
```

Comment: массив если приходит, то foreach ($arr =>$value){ $statement = $connection->prepare("
      INSERT INTO portfolio (image, image_mini) 
      VALUES (:image, :image_mini)
    "); }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function upload_image()
{ $res = array();
 if(isset($_FILES['user_image']))
 {
// Count total files
$countfiles = count($_FILES['user_image']['name']);

for($i=0;$i<$countfiles;$i++){
  $extension = explode('.', $_FILES['user_image']['name'][$i]);
  $new_name = rand() . '.' . $extension[1];
  $destination = '../portfolio/upload/' . $new_name;
  $thumbDestination = '../portfolio/upload/thumb/' . $new_name;

  move_uploaded_file($_FILES['user_image']['tmp_name'][$i], $destination);

  resize($destination, $thumbDestination, 300);
  $res[] = $new_name;
}
return $res;
 }
}
```

запись в массиве

```
    if($_POST["operation"] == "Add")
  {
    $images = array();
    if($_FILES["user_image"]["name"] != '')
    {
      $images = upload_image();
    }
    foreach ($images as $image){
     $statement = $connection->prepare("
       INSERT INTO portfolio (image, image_mini) 
       VALUES (:image, :image_mini)
     ");
     $result = $statement->execute(
       array(
         ':image'       =>  $image,
         ':image_mini'      =>  $image
       )
     );
     if(!empty($result))
     {
       echo 'Фото Добавлено';
     }
   }
  }
```

Comment: Спасибо))) Это работает)))

Comment: `prepare` из цикла бы ещё вынести..

Answer (score -1):

Файлы копируются в цикле, а записываются без цикла.
1 инсерт - 1 запись. 
Если б запись вызавалась в том же цикле, что и копирование - это возможно бы и исправило ситуацию.